# Pytube error while running in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, pytube

I am getting the following error in colab notebook while trying to use pytube for downloading youtube video as mp3 file. I cannot find any solution that works for Colab. Please help me out.

```
RegexMatchError: __init__: could not find match for ^\w+\W
```

Here is my code :

```
for url in url_list:
  print(url)
    # try:
  yt = YouTube(url)
  title = yt.title
  print("processing " + title)
  if os.path.exists(os.path.join(destination, title + ".mp3")):
      print("file exists")
      continue  
  video = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
  print(video)    
  out_file = video.download(output_path=destination)
  base, ext = os.path.splitext(out_file)
  new_file = base + '.mp3'
  os.rename(out_file, new_file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the above issue in the following manner.

1. I forked the github copy of the pytube package
2. Then in a new branch, I made the following edits to cipher.py file of pytube package -In line 30, I replaced `var_regex = re.compile(r"^\w+\W")` with `var_regex = re.compile(r"^\$*\w+\W")`
3. Finally installedthe package in colab from my github branch

```
!pip install pytube@git+https://github.com/priyankaj1311/pytube.git@master_copy
```

Comment: Did it work for you? Still getting the same error in Colab.